# How to Change the Label Strike-Through with light gray on a ChartJS Doughnut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js, web-deployment

I have this ChartJS Doughnut and added an extra Label which will show another value without displaying it on the doughnut. The problem is, ChartJS strikes through labels which are "hidden". Is there a possibilty to change the Strike-Through with a color?

This is my Chart:

[image: This is my Chart]

I want it to look like this Chart:
[image: The Chart I want it to act like]

This is the Source Code:

```
function donutChart(){    
    var ctx = document.getElementById('can');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Misc'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [30, 10, 20],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(126, 214, 223, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(126, 214, 223, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend : {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Inspect the DOM to find the element which has the strikethrough. Then you can amend the CSS to change that rule

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588586/2358409

Comment: @uminder Yes, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jordanwillis answer at a similar question solved my problem.
Thanks to @jordanwillis and @uminder

The Question:
[change legend item style when dataset is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576170/change-legend-item-style-when-dataset-is-hidden/42588586#42588586)